# SSIS 2012 write excel file as blob AND get data from it

Tags: sql, ssis, blob

I have an excel file that I need to import into a couple of SQL Server tables.  One table to store the file as a blob as well as the file attributes: CreatedTime, ModifiedTime, owner, etc.

The other table is to actually import the file's data. I have written a C# Script task to pull the file attributes, but when I try to write the file to SQL Server, I get "Error: Opening file ..." I think this is because SSIS locks the file while it's processing, so it can't open the file to write it?

Comment: You're on the target. Yes, the connection manager is going to lock the file for reading. You *might* be able to set the Data Flow and Excel Connection Manager's `DelayValidation` property to true and ensure your script task is a predecessor task (via precedent constraint)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I did both and same error.  Back to the drawing board...